# Filter array of associative arrays with a dynamic associative array where all elements must be matched

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, filtering, associative-array

I need to filter my indexed array of associative arrays using an associative that may have different combinations of elements and potentially a variable number of elements.

```
$users = [
    [
        "name" => "ali",
        "age" => 22,
        "score" => 12
    ],
    [
        "name" => "hasan",
        "age" => 32,
        "score" => 52
    ],
];
```

And

```
$filters = [
    "name" => "ali",
    "age" => 22
];
```

I need to filter the `$users` array **dynamically** depending on this `$filters`.

```
function filter($item)
{
    // i dont how what should write here
}
$filtered_users = array_filter($users, 'filter');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To filter, you need to iterate over all the filters in the `filterFunc` callback function and check if the filter applies. If one does not apply return false immediatly, else return true:

```
<?php

$users = array(
    0 => array(
    "name" => "ali",
    "age" => 22,
    "score" => 12
    ),
    1 => array(
    "name" => "hasan",
    "age" => 32,
    "score" => 52
    ),
);

$filters = array(
    "name" => "ali",
    "age" => 22
);

function filterFunc($item) {
    global $filters;
    foreach ($filters as $key => $value) {
        if ($item[$key] != $value) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
$filtered_users = array_filter($users, "filterFunc");   
print_r($filtered_users);

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

For a concise, fully functional-style approach, check that there is no remaining, unmatched element in the `$filters` array while comparing each row. This approach will not break even if keys in `$filters` do not exist in the `$users` rows. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/anr3h))

```
var_export(
    array_filter(
        $users,
        fn($row) => !array_diff_assoc($filters, $row)
    )
);
```

---

For best performance, use a conditionally breakable loop which will check each key-value pair in the `filters` array against each row.  This assumes/requires that all keys nominated in `filters` will be guaranteed to exist in the `$users` array. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/ZPeKh))

```
var_export(
    array_filter(
        $users,
        function($row) use($filters) {
            foreach ($filters as $fkey => $fval) {
                if ($row[$fkey] != $fval) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    )
);
```